# Is it possible to embed a webm file in Github readme?

Tags: github

I would like to embed a webm file in my github readme instead of a gif since webm takes a lot less memory.

I tried use the same code which is used to embed gifs but it doesn't work

```
![Alt Text](https://giant.gfycat.com/InfamousGrippingDeinonychus.webm)
```

Comment: Have you tried with plain HTML **<img>** tag ?

Comment: Just tried this `<img src="https://giant.gfycat.com/InfamousGrippingDeinonychus.webm">` , doesn't seem to work

Comment: I tried the **<video><source src='path/to/webm'></video>** html tag too. No joy; does not render in gh markdown.

Answer (score 2):

The support for the WEBM video format mostly depends on the browser (and all modern ones should be able to play it out-of-the-box); I think the problem is that GitHub's Markdown renderer does not recognize the format (yet), and therefore fails to render it in the appropriate `<video>` tag.

[This comment](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/373#issuecomment-801285337) mentions that replacing (or appending) an `.mp4` file extension is a valid workaround for GitHub issues; the file can then be uploaded to GitHub and also displays correctly. That should work for directly embedding in Markdown documents displayed by GitHub, too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, **We can't upload the** **Video but you get similar results.** The thing is GitHub READMEs work perfectly with GIFs. GIF is a bitmap graphical image format. So what you get isn't necessarily a video but the result is relatively similar.

If You want to convert video into gif just go to following
[CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/webm-to-gif)

Then simply **add the GIF in your README.md** file the same way you would add an image

```
![caption](link to image / GIF)
```